# fluid div next to two fixes div's (that have changing size)

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have three div's.

the first two are fixes width,but there width should not be set to permanent size because it could change. (base of the length of text that is there)

then next to those two I have a fluid div that will change his width dynamically when the user change his window size.

how can I set this kind of structure to work? even with the use of javascript

thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "fixed with but not permanent size"?

Comment: there width will not change dynamically like the last div(the fluid one) , but they can't have fixes width bc their width is base on the length of the text content they have.

Comment: In my opinion, that's not possible unless you use JavaScript. Another option (but it's not fully what you want) is perhaps making all 3 columns fluid and using max-width on the 2 columns?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have fixed width divs that resize dynamically unless you use javascript.  Have you played around with min-width and max-width css attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this demo:

for a markup like this:

```
<div id="contentwrapper">
  <div id="contentcolumn">
  ...
  </div>
</div>

<div id="leftcolumn">
  ...
</div>

<div id="rightcolumn">
  ...
</div>
```

CSS

```
#contentwrapper {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -430px;
}

#contentcolumn {
  margin-left: 430px;
}

#leftcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 230px;
  background: #C8FC98;
}

#rightcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  background: #FDE95E;
}
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/sw9422oy/

IF you don't want to set a fixed width then you should use a fluid-fluid-fluid approach like this one: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-33-fluid-fluid-fluid/

Comment: ok,but two divs have fixes width here,I can't see a fixes width bc it will change base of the amount of content there is in those two divs.

Comment: @user3265943 Then consider use a fluid-fluid-fluid layout like this: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-33-fluid-fluid-fluid/. I hope that will help